# FlowLayoutPanel positioning issue in winform

Tags: winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I am having 5 FlowLayoutPanels in my desktop app, each contains dynamically generated buttons (a grid), sometimes more , sometimes less.but its getting very difficult to position all of them without getting overlapped on each other or too far from each other. Question is that is their a simple way that 2nd FlowLayoutPanel just gets drawn below 1st one, 3rd below 2nd one?
What i am trying now is something like this:

```
button_size = 23;
// no_of_rooms = total rows in flowlauoutpanel 
flowLayoutPanel2.Top = (no_of_rooms) * button_size * 1);
flowLayoutPanel2.Top = (no_of_rooms) * button_size * 2);
flowLayoutPanel3.Top = (no_of_rooms) * button_size * 3);
flowLayoutPanel4.Top = (no_of_rooms) * button_size * 4);
flowLayoutPanel5.Top = (no_of_rooms) * button_size * 5);
```

This is the initial image of all FlowLayoutPanels
[Simple FlowlayoutPanels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGI4E.png)

And after dynamically generated buttons i get something like this, overlapped panels on each other [Overlapped FlowLayoutPanels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0J2u.png)

Please tell a simple solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider putting them inside a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: i tried this one, it was getting even more complex to handle

Comment: is their not any way something like this : flowlayoutpanel2.position = flowlayoutpanel1.below;

Comment: flowlayoutpanel.bottom did it for me.